# Using sscanf on an Arduino gives a mismatch with const char * and return value always the same despite different values for the input

Tags: c++, arduino, scanf

The arduino IDE compiler is pretty forgiving and will allow defining variables as "byte" which is a uint8_t or an unsigned char and it seems to run. But it doesn't plug in directly with this test code. I am using the Arduino IDE and PlatformIO to compare results. To debug, I am plugging this code into the OnlineGBD C++ simulator. I need to supply bytes in hex representing binary values as if I plugged it in like this:

const char s[] = { 0x37, 0x74, 0x37, 0 } ;  //  00110111,01110100,00110111,0
writeTextPacket(s)

I have to change "byte b[6]" in the simulator to "char b[6]" to get it to run, but printf looks like it is giving me pointers, not what is in the memory locations. My second Printf tries to format the "b" variable as %p as well as %x for testing and that prepends 0x7ffe in front of the value so (void**)b is 0x7ffexxxxxxxx and the value for b is xxxxxxxx.

And lastly, the return value for nBytes is always "7". It obviously should give me the number of bytes it found. I think I am getting confused between pointers and chars. Thank you.

```
void RegisterList::writeTextPacket(const char *s) volatile{

  int nReg;
  byte b[6];
  int nBytes;
  nBytes=sscanf(s,"%x %x %x %x %x %x",&nReg, b, b+1, b+2, b+3, b+4)-1;  // return number of bytes

  printf("%d\n",nBytes);
  printf("%d, %p, %x, %x, %x, %x, %x", nReg, (void**) b, b, b+1, b+2, b+3, b+4);

  loadPacket(nReg,b,nBytes,0,1);  // loadPacket(int nReg, byte *b, int nBytes, int rep, int flag)
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `%x` with `byte` or `char` at all?

Comment: `scanf` with `%x` must take a pointer to `unsigned int`, according to the C standard.  I doubt Arduino is any different in this respect.  You're passing a pointer to `byte`, so it breaks.  That's all.  You can use `%hhx` if you want to parse a hex value into a `char`.

Comment: This is public domain code from Github. It compiles and runs just fine on Uno/Mega boards and a lot of people have used it for several years now. There are no warnings in the Arduino IDE, but the PlatformIO IDE catches the mismatch between %x and b which is a "byte" with this warning: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int*', but argument 8 has type 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' ". I tried using %p instead of %x, tried specifying b as uint8_t, and unsigned char, but every change just causes a hard error instead of a warning. I am still learning C++, but know Delphi which is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Success! Thank you for the great help. Changing "byte" to "uint8_t" (the Arduino has a "typdef uint8_t byte" to handle this) and substituting %hhx for %x got rid of the warnings. And this test code:

```
  const char *s="16 A9 69 55 C6 A8";
  int nReg;
  uint8_t b[6];
  int nBytes;
  nBytes=sscanf(s,"%d %hhx %hhx %hhx %hhx %hhx",&nReg, b, b+1, b+2, b+3, b+4)-1;  // return number of bytes

  printf("%d\n",nBytes);
  printf("%d, %X, %X, %X, %X, %X", nReg, *b, *(b+1), *(b+2), *(b+3), *(b+4));
```

gives this correct result and counts just the hex numbers that come after the integer nReg number:

5

16, A9, 69, 55, C6, A8